# How can I checkbox id in array in wp_query

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Edit--------
Problem solved, see my reply below for the code!

Sorry for bad English.
I'm making changes to a theme in order to provide the ability to make bulk changes from the dashboard front-end.
I've already managed to provide the same functionality for individual posts, through simple buttons, a function and a little bit of JS.

Now I would like to do the same thing in bulk, but if before reading the IDs of each post it was the button, now it must be a checkbox, which will have to return as an array of IDs to the function.

I did some tests and the code works, not totally.

Because now I can perform the action, but only for a single post, even if I check all post, it performs the action only for the first post checked.

I guess it's a write error in the function in php, I should pass it the propID values ​​as an array, or do a foreach for each (lol) post. But I didn't quite understand how to do it, do you have any suggestions?

This is my code:

button:

```
 <button type="button" class="multi-on-hold btn btn-primary btn-sm">Premi</button>
```

checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="multicheck_prop" name="multicheck_prop[]" value="<?php echo ($post->ID); ?>">
```

function:

```js
add_action( 'wp_ajax_multicheck_houzez_on_hold', 'multicheck_houzez_on_hold' );

if ( !function_exists( 'multicheck_houzez_on_hold' ) ) {
    function multicheck_houzez_on_hold() {

        if ( isset( $_POST['propID'] ) ) {

            global $wpdb;
            if (! isset( $_POST['propID'] ) ) {
                wp_die('No post to put on hold has been supplied!');
            }
            $post_id = absint( $_POST['propID'] );
            
            $post_status = get_post_status( $post_id );

            if($post_status == 'publish') { 
                $post = array(
                    'ID'            => $post_id,
                    'post_status'   => 'on_hold'
                );
            } elseif ($post_status == 'on_hold') {
                $post = array(
                    'ID'            => $post_id,
                    'post_status'   => 'publish'
                );
            }
            $post_id =  wp_update_post($post);
        }
            return true;
    }
}


js: 

    

            $('.multi-on-hold').on( 'click', function( e ) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $this = $( this );
            var propid = $this.data( 'property' );
            var checkboxVals = $('.multicheck_prop');
    
            var vals = $('.multicheck_prop:checked').map(function(){return this.value;}).get().join(',')
    
            if(vals == "") {
                return;
            }
            
            $.ajax({
                
                url: ajax_url,
                data: {
                    'action': 'multicheck_houzez_on_hold',
                    'propID': vals,
                },
                method: 'POST',
                dataType: "JSON",
                
                beforeSend: function( ) {
                    //window.alert(vals)
                    houzez_processing_modal(processing_text);
                },
                success: function( response ) {
                    window.location.reload();
                },
                complete: function(){
                }
            });               
        });
```

Comment: Are you able to get value to the ajax side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to send many IDs to PHP, you can just loop over them as you pointed out.
This would support both one or many ids:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_multicheck_houzez_on_hold', 'multicheck_houzez_on_hold' );

if ( !function_exists( 'multicheck_houzez_on_hold' ) ) { 
    if (isset($_POST['propID'])) {

            global $wpdb;
            if (!isset($_POST['propID'])) {
                wp_die('No post to put on hold has been supplied!');
            }
            // convert propID to array if it isnt
            $prop_ids = !is_array($_POST['propID']) ? [$_POST['propID']] : $_POST['propID'];

            foreach ($prop_ids as $prop_id) {
                $post_id = absint($prop_id);

                $post_status = get_post_status($post_id);

                if ($post_status == 'publish') {
                    $post = array(
                        'ID'            => $post_id,
                        'post_status'   => 'on_hold'
                    );
                } elseif ($post_status == 'on_hold') {
                    $post = array(
                        'ID'            => $post_id,
                        'post_status'   => 'publish'
                    );
                }
                $post_id =  wp_update_post($post);
            }
        }
        return true;

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You for the reply! Unfortunately, this solution doesn't change anything. The code work only on first checkbox selected, so only on the first ID.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in checkbox name `multicheck_prop[]` you define as an array so you have to access as an array. check below code.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_multicheck_houzez_on_hold', 'multicheck_houzez_on_hold' );

if ( !function_exists( 'multicheck_houzez_on_hold' ) ) { 
    function multicheck_houzez_on_hold() {

        global $wpdb;

        if (! isset( $_POST['propID'] ) ) {
            wp_die('No post to put on hold has been supplied!');
        }

        if( !empty( $_POST['propID'] ) ){

            foreach ( (array) $_POST['propID'] as $key => $propID ) {
                
                $post_id = absint( $propID );
                
                $post_status = get_post_status( $post_id );

                if($post_status == 'publish') { 
                    $post = array(
                        'ID'            => $post_id,
                        'post_status'   => 'on_hold'
                    );
                } elseif ($post_status == 'on_hold') {
                    $post = array(
                        'ID'            => $post_id,
                        'post_status'   => 'publish'
                    );
                }
                $post_id =  wp_update_post($post);
            }
            wp_send_json_success();
        }

        wp_send_json_error();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Your code brick the script, with an error in php on this row: 
foreach (($_POST['propID']) as $key => $propID ) {

Ther error is: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Answer (score 0):

Issue Solved! I've changed a piece of code to recognize the 'ID' in array and implement the solution of @Suver1.

Thank you for the suggestions!

This is my working code:

```js
$('.multi-on-hold').on( 'click', function( e ) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $this = $( this );
            var propid = $this.data( 'property' );
            //var Nonce = $this.data('nonce');
    
            var checkboxVals = $('.multicheck_prop');
            //var vals = $('.multicheck_prop:checked').map(function(){return this.value;}).get().join(',')
            var vals = $('.multicheck_prop:checked').map(function(){return this.value;}).toArray();
    
            if(vals == "") {
                return;
            }
            
            $.ajax({
                
                url: ajax_url,
                data: {
                    'action': 'multicheck_houzez_on_hold',
                    'propID': vals,
                },
                method: 'POST',
                dataType: "JSON",
                
                beforeSend: function( ) {
                    //window.alert(vals), // See the value of any ID
                    houzez_processing_modal(processing_text);
                },
                 success: function( response ) {
                    window.location.reload();
                },
                complete: function(){
                }
            });
               
        });
```

```html
if ( !function_exists( 'multicheck_houzez_on_hold' ) ) {
    function multicheck_houzez_on_hold() {
        if ( isset( $_POST['propID'] ) ) {
        global $wpdb;
        if (! isset( $_POST['propID'] ) ) {
            wp_die('No post to put on hold has been supplied!');
        }
            // convert propID to array if it isnt -- Thanks to Suver1
            $post_ids = !is_array($_POST['propID']) ? [$_POST['propID']] : $_POST['propID'];
            foreach ($post_ids as $post_id)  {
                $post_status = get_post_status( $post_id );
                if($post_status == 'publish') { 
                    $post = array(
                        'ID'            => $post_id,
                        'post_status'   => 'on_hold'
                    );
                } elseif ($post_status == 'on_hold') {
                    $post = array(
                        'ID'            => $post_id,
                        'post_status'   => 'publish'
                    );
                }
                $post_id =  wp_update_post($post);
            } // End foreach
        } // End IF
        return true;
    } // End this function
} // End function exists
```